# I am using Canon SDK Tutorial V11 , but I get an error SDK Error:0x7 when I open the session

Tags: c#, canon-sdk

I have update the Canon.EDSDK to V 3.6.1,. I have tried couple of solution but non seems to remedy the situation.

[Here it the image of error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE7sv.jpg)

Comment: From e.g. here https://gist.github.com/kritzikratzi/808508 , it's `EDS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED` error. Looks like the camera model is not supported

Answer (score 1):

as @Renat has noted, your camera model is not supported with SDK version 3.6.1. The EOS 4000D is only supported since SDK version 3.8.0